# Three Of Each Of

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I have three $1 bills, three $5 bills, three $10 bills.  I want use "*each*" to describe them:

> 1. I have three ***of each*** of $1 bills, $5 bills, and $10 bills.
> 2. I have three ***each*** of $1 bills, $5 bills, and $10 bills.

Is one of them wrong?

Comment: Idiomatic is "*n* each of x, y, and.z" or "*n* of each".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either is them is *wrong* especially when spoken--you'll be understood. In a written context, I think #1 would look better as *I have three of each: $1 bills, $5 bills, and $10 bills*--to me, there's something a little awkward looking about having multiple "ofs" close together in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay and both are used.  Probably a matter of taste which is preferred.  I like the second form--but I like breviloquence.  Someone more concerned with really pinning things down with overengineered sentences would go for the former.

On slightly further thought, I should note I'm thinking of writing.  In speech the needless repetition is less noticeable to both the speaker and listener.